# Is Collectd a good choice for gathering system metrics

Tags: monitoring, system-monitoring

I had some experience with collectd a year or so back. I remember being impressed by its speed and flexibility, however it was never adopted as the main source of collecting metrics, cron jobs running scripts to send data to statsd/graphite/nagios remained the defacto choice.

The subject has has come up again recently after some of the metrics gathered where deemed to be less than accurate.

And I was wondering if collectd is still considered to be a good choice for such a task, or has something better appeared that can do the job.

The requirements for the gathering of metrics are:

- they are collected at least once minute
- easily deployed via puppet or chef
- depth of support for things like the JVM, system processes, MySQL, postgress, haproxy and other such opensource platform components

I would be interested in hearing from anyone with experience in this area

Answer (score 1):

Collectd is a good choice for collecting and presenting statistics. It can collect from multiple sources and if you are after in-depth statistics and data aggregations from certain applications, you can feed statd output into collectd. You can then send the stuff to Nagios/Icinga and/or Graphite.

- Collectd can be configured to collect in 1-second steps through the
  `interval` directive.
- Can't talk for puppet or chef, but deployment via Salt works flawlessly.
- Can't answer to your specific examples, but collectd has many, many plugins (a quick glance shows MySQL, Postgre and a generic Java plugin) and collects all data systat collects by   itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend Collectd over some home-brew shell script solution (really, anything is better than failure-prone shell scripts).

It's really lightweight and doesn't use much resources, can be easily extended with either [Python](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Python) or even by [reusing your existing shell scripts](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Exec) so even if it lacks modules for a particular service you'd like to monitor, you can easily make one.

A minute interval isn't an issue as the default interval is even lower, [set to 10 seconds](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Interval).

I can't speak for any configuration management tools compatibility unfortunately but it should be good, especially since many distros provide packaged versions of it that you can just mention in your Puppet/Chef files.

Comment: Personal experience, though a bit off-topic : it worked flawlessly for monitoring a crap consumer-grade router (with no SNMP obviously), had to write a small Python module to screen-scrape its web interface.